# Java - Reading a text file when a certain sequence occurs

Tags: java

I haven't been able to find a way to read from a .txt file when a certain sequence occurs.

This is how an entry from my file looks like:

```
&1551:John:Packard:83:Heavy:Blonde&
```

I want my file to be read from &1551 (1551 is the unique ID number of the user) until the next "&". Do you guys have any suggestions as to how to accomplish this? The ":" is later used for splitting the string.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a single record per line why not read the file line by line until you encounter `&1551`? Should be easy to find some code how to read a file line by line.

Comment: Each entry is written in a separate line?

Comment: Search for the `&[^&]*&` pattern ?

Comment: Just read the entire line (or text) and save it to the `string`, then modify the `string` the way you need it. I mean you definitely need to read the whole `.txt` to find ampersands.

Comment: show us what you have tried..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple JDK `Scanner` has the ability to read a file stopping at certain patterns:

> ```
> public String findWithinHorizon(String pattern,
>                             int horizon)
> ```
>
> Attempts to find the next occurrence of the specified pattern.
>
> ```
> public Scanner skip(Pattern pattern)
> ```

Skips input that matches the specified pattern, ignoring delimiters. This method will skip input if an anchored match of the specified pattern succeeds.

If a match to the specified pattern is not found at the current position, then no input is skipped and a `NoSuchElementException` is thrown.

So this should be enough:

```
    // skip anything up to "$1551:" (but keep "1551:" for next read)
    Pattern toSkip = Pattern.compile(".*?\\$(?=1511:)", Pattern.DOTALL);
    sc.skip(toSkip);
    // get everything starting at the "1551:" up to a "$" sign on same line
    String line = sc.findWithinHorizon(".*(?=\\$)", 0);
```

If end of lines can be included between the `$` signs, then you should compile the pattern with the `DOTALL` flag as I did for `toSkip`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will have to get input from string without staring & and ending &,

then split string by :

So, Assuming all inputs will be in new line below code should work,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://test.txt"));
        String sCurrentLine;
        String[] fields;
        while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sCurrentLine = sCurrentLine.substring(sCurrentLine.indexOf('&') + 1);
            sCurrentLine = sCurrentLine.substring(0, sCurrentLine.indexOf('&'));
            fields = sCurrentLine.split(":");
            for (String tmp : fields)
                System.out.println(tmp);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in accepting String");
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Remember to close the BufferedReader.